# Folders in Finder not showing

Tags: macos, finder, preferences, sidebar

This may be a total noob question, but this is my first apple product, please bear with me. 
I'm not seeing certain folders, like "movies", "music", and "pictures" in finder. 
Is there a way to activate these folders?

I'm running osx mavericks on a late 2013 mbp.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious as to why Apple decided that a truncated, minimal list of our folders should be the default view? As for the one who said to select show/hide on the folder itself... that's kind of hard to do when apple has decided to not ever let you see the folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pull down the **Finder** menu and select **Preferences...**

[image]

In the Preferences dialog, along the top row, click on the **Sidebar** tab.
Check the boxes next to the items you want to see in the sidebar of every Finder window.

[image]

Close the **Finder Preferences** window and you are good to go.

Answer (score -3):

Nothing to these critical stuffs.

Just Try This

for OS X EI CAPITAN 10.11.6

Move the " Cursor" on to the folder Like " Favorite". there will appear " Show" or "Hide" option.
Click on " SHOW " option. All the functions will appear.